# Conjoint experiment: How to formally test if effect sizes for attribute levels are significantly different from each other

Tags: r, cjoint

I am doing conjoint analysis in R, working with the Cregg-package by Thomas Leeper. I am estimating AMCEs (all good up to this point, getting nice plots, etc.)

Now, I want to formally test whether the estimated effect of one attribute level is significantly different from the estimated effect of another attribute level within the same dimension (just for the simple AMCE, no subgroups).

Anybody has an idea of how to do that? Any solution for cjoint (or STATA) would also be most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.